# Minimum spanning tree algorithm.

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms

Is the following a valid algorithm for finding a minimum spanning tree?

> Given a weighted graph with unique weights, remove the all edges that are the highest cost edge in any cycle *of the original full graph*.

Edit: I've changed the description to draw more attention to the differences between this an Kruskal's algorithm (which it is NOT.) Kruskal's algorithm is iterative, this is just a predicate that can be tested on the original unmodified graph.

Comment: maybe this is a good example of something off topic as being too easy to find on wikipedia ?

Comment: I agree to Suresh.

Comment: @ilyaraz: I've looked into this some before and never seen the characterization you referenced in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it is correct. You can characterize MST as a tree such that every edge outside it is a maximum edge in the corresponding cycle. The proof is an easy excersise.

Comment: Do you have a reference to such a characterization? -- I think you are correct, but I'm not 100% sure that that shows that the edges in the MSP *can't* be a minimum edge in *any* cycle.

Comment: @BCS: I think you mean you're not sure that that shows that the edges in the MST can't be a *maximum* edge in any cycle, right? Consider any cycle in the original graph, with maximum edge length between u and v, and suppose that there is an MST containing uv.  Deleting that edge gives a graph with a u-containing component and a v-containing component.  Now convince yourself that there must be at least 2 edges on the original cycle that span these 2 components: we already know there must be at least 1 (the edge we just deleted), and if you trace around the cycle you must...

Comment: ...come back to the component you started from at least once.  So, there are at least 2 spanning edges, and adding either one will reconnect the graph.  Adding back any of the non-uv (= non-max-length) edges will produce a connected graph with shorter length than we started with, hence the original graph could not have been a MST.  (Proof by contradiction.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a well-defined algorithm. You can tweak it to make it well-defined, by changing the description to

```
Remove all edges, from high to low weight, that do not make the graph disconnected.
```

and this is equivalent to kruskal's algorithm.

Comment: This algo is not iterative. Kruskal's is. This algo only looks at the origonal graph. Kruskal's looks at the graph after edges have been removed. This algo is not Kruskal's.